# Why is ~0xF equal to 0xFFFFFFF0 on a 32-bit machine?

Tags: c, operators

Why is ~0xF equal to 0xFFFFFFF0?

Also, how is `~0xF && 0x01 = 1`? Maybe I don't get 0x01 either.

Comment: `&&` is logical AND, not bitwise AND. ~ is a standard bitwise operation.

Comment: I know what ~ does, but I thought 0xF (even on a 32bit) would be 0x11111111?

Comment: `0xF` is `0x0000000F`. In what world would that be equal to `0x11111111`?

Comment: I think I get it, 0xF is 0x1, but on a 32bit, we have to add padding of 0's right? that makes it 0x0000000F, right?

Comment: " 0xF is 0x1" -- No, 0xF is 0xF. "we have to add padding of 0's right? that makes it 0x0000000F, right?" 0xF == 0x0F == 0x00F == 0x000F ... == 0x0000000F == 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F on all machines.

Comment: "~0xF && 0x01 = 1" -- a && b is 1 if both a and b are non-zero, which they are here.

Comment: Thinking of it in terms of a and b makes perfect sense, thanks! I was mixing & and &&, got it!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Question 1**

> Why is ~0xF equal to 0xFFFFFFF0?

First, this means you run this on a 32-bit machine. That means 0xF is actually `0x0000000F` in [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal),

And that means 0xF is
`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111` in binary representation.

The `~` operator means the NOT operation. Tt changes *every 0 to 1 and every 1 to 0* in the binary representation. That would make ~0xF to be:
`1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000` in binary representation.

And that is actually `0xFFFFFFF0`.

Note that if you do this on a 16-bit machine, the answer of `~0xF` would be `0xFFF0`.

**Question 2**

You wrote the wrong statement, it should be `0xF & 0x1`. Note that `0x1` `0x01`, `0x001`, and `0x0001` are all the same. So let’s change this hexdecimal number to binary representation:

`0xF` would be:

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111`

and `0x1` would be:

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`

The `&` operation follows the following rules:

```
0 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

So doing that to every bit, you get the result:

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`

which is actually `0x1`.

**Additional**

`|` means bitwise OR operation. It follows:

```
0 | 0 = 0
0 | 1 = 1
1 | 0 = 1
1 | 1 = 1
```

`^` means bitwise XOR operation. It follows:

```
0 ^ 0 = 0
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 0 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0
```

You can get more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR).

Comment: Just for the record, the list of rules given for AND, OR, and XOR are called truth tables, if it makes them easier to find.

Answer (score 3):

If you store 0xF in a 32-bit "int", all 32 bits flip, so ~0xF = 0xFFFFFFF0.

See this:
http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8214/08w/notes/bit_operations.txt

They give a good explanation

Comment: it is true even for C. 0x represents a hexadecimal representation. @oldrinb

Comment: see §6.4.4.1¶5 of the C99 standard, though. `0xF` uses `int` representation :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're negating 0xF, which flips all of the bits to their inverse. So for example, with 8 bits you have: `0xF = 00001111`. If you Negate that, it turns into `11110000`.

Since you're using 32 bits, the F's are just extended all the way out. `1111 .... 0000`

For your second question, you're using a logical AND, not a bitwise AND. Those two behave entirely differently.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your confusion is that you believe 0xF is the same as 0b1111111111111111.  It is not, it is 0b0000000000001111.

Answer (score 0):

~0xF inverts all its bits, going

```
from 0x0000000F = 00000000000000000000000000001111 (32 bits) 
to   0xFFFFFFF0 = 11111111111111111111111111110000 (32 bits)
```

a && b is 1 if both a and b are non-zero, and ~0xF and 0x01 are both non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

In C, `~0xF` can never be equal to `0xFFFFFFF0`. The former is a negative number (in any of the three signed representations C allows) and the latter is a positive number. However, if both are converted to a 32-bit unsigned type on a twos-complement implementation, the converted values will be equal.

As for `~0xF && 0x01`, the `&&` operator is logical and, not bitwise and.